# Finish old instance of activity and start new instance of the same activity

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, activity-stack

I have MenuActivity with two buttons "New Game" and "Resume" with onClick methods newGame() and resume() respectively

- newGame() method starts GameActivity and finishes MenuActivity.
- resume() method. When resume(), MenuActivity finishes itself and which in effect
  will automatically resume GameActivity. Because it will be in back stack. Why it will be in back stack? In GameActivity the onBackPressed method starts MenuActivity, but doesn't finish itself, thus stays in back stack.

> ```
>  public class MenuActivity extends Activity{
>     ...
>     public void newGame(View view){
>       Intent intent = new Intent(this,GameActivity.class);
>       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
>       startActivity(intent);
>       this.finish();  
>   }
>       public void resume(View view){
>       this.finish();
>   }
> }
> ```

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity{
...
    @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent inMain=new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(inMain, 0);
    }}
```

The scenario is following: new game button pressed, i.e. MenuActivity is finished and GameActivity is started. At some point in game user presses back button and it will start MenuActivity. In the MenuActivity user presses to new game button again. It should finish old instance of GameActivity completely and release all the memory it is holding and start new instance from scratch. However right now when new game is started the old version is still in memory, and I can see it from the DDMS allocated memory. How would I reach the desirable effect as I described?

Comment: In MenuActivity, you are starting FireRoomActivity, not GameActivity as you described.

Comment: yes, thank you. I forgot to change the name. But that's not the problem

Comment: Show your manifest please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a new `GameActivity` from your `MenuActivity`, then just have the `MenuActivity` return a special result code to the `GameActivity`. In `GameActivity.onActivityResult()` if the special result code is returned, you should start a new `GameActivity` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Do you mean having in MenuActivity.newGame(){ setResult(RESULT_CLOSE_ALL);
  this.finish(); 
 }
and in the GameActivity.onActivityResult(){ 
switch(resultCode)
     {
     case RESULT_CLOSE_ALL:
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();} ???

Comment: But that will close my app when I start the game first time as there is nothing in backstack

Comment: I don't think so. It starts the `GameActivity` again.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == 1) {

 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
     String result=data.getStringExtra("result");      
     //Check the result if it is resume just continue
     // else
     /* What about starting the activity from here itself */
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     finish();
     startActivity(intent);
 }
 if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
     //Write your code if there's no result
 }
 }
}
```